# How to make DELETE faster in fast changing (DELSERT) table in MonetDB?

Tags: indexing, dml, monetdb

I am using MonetDB (MDB) for OLAP queries. I am storing source data in PostgreSQL (PGSQL) and syncing it with MonetDB in batches written in Python.

In PGSQL there is a wide table with ID (non-unique) and few columns. Every few seconds Python script takes a batch of 10k records changed in the PGSQL and uploads them to MDB.

The process of upload to MDB is as follows:

1. Create staging table in MDB
2. Use `COPY` command to upload 10k records into the staging table.
3. `DELETE` from destination table all IDs that are in staging table.
4. `INSERT` to the destination table all rows from staging table.

So, it is basically a `DELETE & INSERT`. I cannot use `MERGE` statement, because I do not have a PK - one ID can have multiple values in the destination. So I need to do a delete and full insert for all IDs currently synced.

Now to the problem: the `DELETE` is slow.

When I do a `DELETE` on a destination table, deleting 10k records in table of 25M rows, it will take 500ms.

However! If I run simple `SELECT * FROM destination WHERE id = 1` and THEN do a `DELETE`, it takes 2ms.

I think that it has something to do with automatic creation of auxiliary indices. But this is where my knowledge ends.

I tried to solve this problem of "pre-heating" by doing the lookup myself and it works - but only for the first `DELETE` after pre-heat.

Once I do `DELETE` and `INSERT`, the next `DELETE` gets again slow. And doing the pre-heating before each `DELETE` does not make sense, because the pre-heat itself takes 500ms.

Is there any way on how to sync data to MDB without breaking auxiliary indices already built? Or make the `DELETE` faster without pre-heat? Or should I use some different technique to sync data into MDB without PK (does `MERGE` has the same problem?).

Thanks!

Comment: which MonetDB version are you using?

Comment: Great question, sorry for missing it. We are running Oct2020

Comment: Thanks. this version already contains some recent improvements for HASH rebuild and handling deletes. Let me see if someone else has more ideas.

PS> which OS are you using?

Comment: PPS> Can you also provide some HW info (e.g. #CPUs, RAM)? Is this on bare-metal HW or a cloud instance?  Is the timing repeatable? what's the table schema and the exact delele query? Can you provide a TRACE of the slow delete?

Comment: We are running it inside Docker image based on python:3.7, linux server as a host (Ubuntu 20.04LTS)

Comment: 8 cores, 32GB RAM, droplet in DigitalOcean. We can see the same thing in all instances (~6) we are running, they have different volumes of data, but same thing happening.

Comment: I dont' have much Docker experiences myself, but next than that, all look very normal.  Would be interesting to see where the time is spent, so, a first thing is to look at the DELETE query trace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225943/discussion-between-vojtch-kurka-and-jennie).